# Get the current section in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck with a JQuery script. The structure is something like that:

```
<section class="slider" id="1">
    <section class="photo-home">
        <img src="images/media/the_file1.jpg" />
    </section>           
    <section class="photo-home">
        <img src="images/media/the_file2.jpg" />
    </section>
            <!-- ... etc -->
</section>

<section class="controls">
    <a name="prev">PREV</a>
    <a name="next">NEXT</a>
</section>
```

The problem is to get the current .photo-home selected. Considering I have lots of '.slider' identifying with different id's. BTW I'm adding the class .current to the current .photo-home section. The problem is to enable/disable the buttons (next/prev)... Does anybody know how to do it?

This is the JQuery

```
<script>
    $('.slider-photo .photo-home:first-child').addClass('current');

    $('.slider-photo a[name="prev"]').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.slider-photo').attr('id');
        var curr = // HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK :(
            if (curr > 0){
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            }
    });
    $('.slider-photo a[name="next"]').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.slider-photo').attr('id');
        var total = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.photo-home').length;
        var curr = // HERE IS THE PROBLEM! :(
        if (curr <= total){
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "BTW I'm adding the class .current to the current"  - wait, what? that means you're able to *access the current section*. "*The problem is to enable/disable the buttons"* - what? when? I think you need to totaly rephrase the question...

Comment: OK, I'll try again (and please forgive me because English is not my native tongue). I just want to enable / disable the NEXT and PREV buttons depending if there is next or previous images in the slider I am depending on which image I'm viewing... Do you understand?

Comment: Yes i understand. English is not an issue mate, Somehow others have to understand the issue you're trying to solve, that's all. So there is only one set of buttons if i understood correctly. Some demo code of how you're switing between the images will help us help you...

Comment: Thank you. OK, I'll edit the post and add the JQuery as I have now. But it's a little embarrassed because I'm sure of my very bad JQuery

Comment: The problem is when I have more than one slider... I was happy whilst I had just one... Thank you for the closest() advice. I'll try!

Comment: So this `prev` and `next` buttons are common for multiple sliders?!!

Comment: No. Each slider has their own next/prev buttons! :(

Comment: Where is the common parent that wraps the slider and these buttons? What is `.slider-photo` ? if it is the parent, check the updated answer... or share the exact `HTML`

Comment: Yes. The structure is exactly I've posted. .slider-photo = .slider. I made it shorter to clean the code. I have lots of .slider-photo with their (n) .photo-home and ONE .control inside each one. I identify the .slider-photo with the ID because, as I told you, whilst I had just one: everything was fine. The caos began when I added another .slider-photo section...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly (*From comments*) you can check whether there is any more images using the [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) and [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) functions.

Assuming you have the reference to current section in `this`, you can do something like

```
if($(this).nextAll(".photo-home").length){ //next photo available
  $(".controls a[name='next']").prop("disabled",false);
}
else{
  //next photo not available
  $(".controls a[name='next']").prop("disabled",true);
}
if($(this).prevAll(".photo-home").length){ //prev photo available
  $(".controls a[name='prev']").prop("disabled",false);
}
else{
  //prev photo not available
  $(".controls a[name='prev']").prop("disabled",true);
}
```

**Update:**

From what i understood, your code should be something like

```
$('.slider-photo a[name="next"]').click(function() {
    var $parentSlide= $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.slider-photo'); // Access the slider element
    var $curr = $parentSlide.find(".current").parent(".photo-home"); // find the current section
    if($curr.nextAll(".photo-home").length){ //next photo available
      $(".controls a[name='next']").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else{ //next photo not available
      $(".controls a[name='next']").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's almost done! I added: "var curr = $('#'+id).find('.current').index('.photo-home');". The problem is curr gives the index absolute, not relative. I mean, if I have two sliders (with 2 and 3 pics, is 5 in total). curr gives me: 1, 2... 5 instead of 1, 2 and 1, 2, 3.... Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

DOOOOOOOONNNNNNNEEEEEE!!!!

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    $('.slider-photo .photo-home:first-child').addClass('current');

    $('.slider-photo a[name="prev"]').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.slider-photo').attr('id');
        var idt = '#'+id;
        var curr = $(idt).find('.current').index(idt+' .photo-home');
            if (curr > 0){
                $(idt).find('.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            }
    });
    $('.slider-photo a[name="next"]').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.slider-photo').attr('id');
        var idt = '#'+id;
        var total = $(idt).find('.photo-home').length-1;
        var curr = $(idt).find('.current').index(idt+' .photo-home');
        if (curr < total){
            $(idt).find('.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure it would be better but it works as I wanted.
THANK YOU TJ FOR YOUR HELP!!